# How do I verify the Subject of X509 Certificate using rails-auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi, ruby-2.2

I am trying to secure one endpoint that I have for the Docusign Connect API. I have checked the **Sign Message with X509 Certificate** on docusign connect API configuration.

The Client Certificate Common Name is added to the Docusign Account as well.

I am trying to validate the subject sent using the rails-auth gem.

Following is the content of the ACL file(acl.yml)

```
---
- resources:
  - method: POST
    path: /
  allow_x509_subject:
    cn: "the common name"
```

I have added the following in the config.ru file

```
app = Rails.application
acl = Rails::Auth::ACL.from_yaml(                               
  File.read("path of the acl.yml"),                    
  matchers: { allow_x509_subject: Rails::Auth::X509::Matcher }  
)                                                               

acl_auth = Rails::Auth::ACL::Middleware.new(app, acl: acl)      

x509_auth = Rails::Auth::X509::Middleware.new(                  
  acl_auth,                                                     
  ca_file: "path_to_the_pem_file.crt",
  cert_filters: { 'X-SSL-Client-Cert' => :pem })                                                               

run x509_auth
```

I am getting the following exception.

> *** Exception Rails::Auth::NotAuthorizedError in Rack application object (unauthorized request)

The Common Name that is added in the Docusign Account is the same as the one that I have mentioned in YML file. Could somebody please help me in finding the issue here?

I am using Ruby 2.2.2 with rails 4.2.2, rails-auth 2.0.3

Answer (score 0):

The best way to secure connect endpoint and ensure that all calls are coming from DocuSign is to use HMAC Security.

When using HMAC security, each message sent from your DocuSign Connect account includes additional header values, one for each HMAC key you have defined (up to one hundred), which will contain the message body hashed with one of your HMAC keys, using HMACSHA256. For example, if you have defined two keys then two headers, X-DocuSign-Signature-1 and X-DocuSign-Signature-2, will be added. They will contain the message body hashed with your first and second secret keys, respectively.

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect-hmac